strip.white doesn't work in r if the data frame is too large
I import, clean, and merge two different data sets that are created from Qualtrics surveys.  I use read.csv to load the data, and I have strip.white=TRUE to remove leading and trailing spaces.  If I filter the import data down to a normal day's import (30 rows or so), this works fine and there is no white space.  If I import the entire dataset without filtering the date first in excel (about 1100 rows), it doesn't strip the white space.  I can't figure it out at all.
The code below is it.  That is all of it.  I run the r script in chunks to quality check it when there is an issue.  This is the first chunk, and the white space is present immediately after pulling in the data.  Any thoughts about how what might be wrong or what I can do to fix it?
#define date
testing_date_pipe <- ("071724")
student_file <- paste(testing_date_pipe,"_Student.csv", sep = "")
evaluator_file <- paste (testing_date_pipe,"_Evaluator.csv", sep = "")

#turn on the filter: set the value as 'TRUE' to keep the filter or 'FALSE' to turn it off


#define path to raw data
registration_location <- here::here("data", "raw_data", "1_unified_testing", testing_date_pipe, student_file)
evaluation_location <- here::here("data", "raw_data", "1_unified_testing", testing_date_pipe, evaluator_file)

#load raw data
registration <- read.csv(registration_location, strip.white=TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
evaluation <- read.csv(evaluation_location, strip.white=TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")


Welcome to SO.  If your code "works" with one set of data and doesn't with another, then the problem is probably due to a difference in the data.  Which yiou haven't shown us.  So it's going to be difficult to help you.

What are you doing to the data in Excel?

Thanks for the feedback.  Long time lurker on SO, finally getting to where I think I can contribute.  The data is difficult to share, Limey, as it is all PII.  I pull the data as a .csv from Qualtrics, rename the two files so that R Studio can find them, and then run the script.  If I sort the .csv by date, and then delete every row that isn't the date in question, it works.  This is a concern because white space in one data frame is preventing me from merging with the other as the primary key doesn't match.

I'll get to the bottom of the why, but it looks like the problem is the way that I am saving the file in general.  I opened the unfiltered file, saved it, and closed it without changing a single thing, and then the strip.white worked no problem. Thanks for being willing, sorry to waste your time.
